# Using two data frames for a PCR in R

Tags: r

I am a biologist and I did research on biodiversity on several locations. Moreover, I measured environmental variables in those plots. Normally, I would analyse this data in Canoco5, however, I am trying to learn R as well. My data frames look like this:

```
          Arthopleidae Baetinae Cloeninae Caenidae etc.
Location_1           0        3        16        0
Location_2           0        0         0        5
Location_3           0        1        40        0
Etc.
```

And:

```
                    pH  Temperature Vegetation etc.
Location_1         8.22       28.06          0
Location_2         8.15       28.95         30
Location_3         8.29       28.75          0
Etc.
```

I cannot find a package which is suitable for this kind of analysis. What would you reccomend?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: hi! what kind of analysis are you trying to do?

Comment: Is there a time series, i.e. several measurements for each location?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions asking us to suggest, find or recommend a book, tool, software library, plug-in, tutorial, explain a technique or provide any other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow. For questions about [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) you'd use the link. But sometimes you are lucky and people here still like to help.

Comment: What's about using [Geospatial Analysis in R](http://data-analytics.net/cep/Schedule_files/geospatial.html)? Of course, only if you also have coordinates of your locations.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [vegan package](https://github.com/vegandevs/vegan/) (available in CRAN or GitHub). It has all of the ordination methods available in Canoco5 and integrates will with other R packages (eg., zoo, tidy). I would consider `vegan` a modern "drop-in" replacement for Canoco and has some nonparametric methods available as well (eg., non-metric MDS).

Here is the package description.

> The vegan package provides tools for descriptive community ecology. It
>   has most basic functions of diversity analysis, community ordination
>   and dissimilarity analysis. Most of its multivariate tools can be used
>   for other data types as well.